# asp validation for multiple spaces between strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I've a textbox for name field where I've used asp validation for proper name format. I want to validate multiple spaces between the strings. How can I do that? The leading and trail spaces are removed by trim() function but how can I validate multiple spaces between the strings? like

```
multiple    spaces

no   space
```

My validation code::

```
<label>
    <span>Full name</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_name" runat="server" required="required"/>      
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_txt_name" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_name" ForeColor="Red" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid name!" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,50}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

</label>
```

Comment: Do you need to limit the whole string to 50 chars? You mean `"one two three"` is valid and `"one<SPACE><SPACE>two<SPACE><SPACE>three"` is not?

Comment: yes but character count is optional. Thank You!

Comment: Well, if it is optional, you may just use `^[a-zA-Z'.]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z'.]+)*$`. If not, `^(?=.{2,50}$)[a-zA-Z'.]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z'.]+)*$`.

Comment: Thank You! what if I've to validate it using character count also.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please can you provide the answer so that I can mark it as correct reply for future reference. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are using allows matching whitespace anywhere inside the string and any occurrences, consecutive or not, since it is part of a rather generic character class. You need to use a grouping and quantify it accordingly:

```
^(?=.{2,50}$)[a-zA-Z'.]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z'.]+)*$
```

Note that the `(?=.{2,50}$)` lookahead requires the whole line to be of 2 to 50 chars long.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WOtQQz/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2,50}$)` - a positive lookahead requiring any 2 to 50 chars other than a newline up to the end of the string
- `[a-zA-Z'.]+` - 1+ letters, single quote or dot chars
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group start:

  - `\s` -  1 whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z'.]+` - 1+ letters, single quote or dot chars
- `)*` - zero or more (`*`) occurrences
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thank You for the nice explanation. Your description will be help others to understand regular expression in future also. Thank You!!!